# Create a spring bean which call a url with headers

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, applicationcontext

I have following property **url.xyz** in properties file which will be read in spring applicationcontext.xml file

```
url.xyz=https://test.com/?name=sample&id=123
```

I want to further add headers to it for example

```
'cache-control:no cache'
'content type:text/plain'
```

Above url returns a password.
I want to create a bean in Spring which will invoke url above with headers and return the password

```
  <bean id=pwd" class="java.lang.String">
        ????
   </bean>
```

how can this be acheived?

Comment: You add headers to a HTTP request, not to an URL .

Comment: Can you please tell me know can i create a spring bean which connects to the url with urls ? This url returns a password when called

Comment: You need to create a class that will do that, and then instantiate it as a bean.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests for some examples on actually making http requests and handling responses.